# Dns filezone setup with mx and spf

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, spf, reverse-dns, ptr-record

I am trying to create a mail server. I bought the domain **mastermails.info** on godaddy.com. I am struggling with the setup of DNS. Whenever I change something in the **MX** record to make my server available for receiving emails by SMTP, I break something in the **SPF** record. Whenever I try to fix the **SPF** record, I get errors from the [Kitterman testing tools](http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html), that it's not valid:

> ```
> The TXT records found for your domain are:
> v=spf1 mx ptr ip4:137.117.148.231 ptr:mastermails.info mx:secureserver.net -all
>
> Checking to see if there is a valid SPF record.
>
> Found v=spf1 record for mastermails.info:
> v=spf1 mx ptr ip4:137.117.148.231 ptr:mastermails.info mx:secureserver.net -all
>
> evaluating...
> Results - PermError SPF Permanent Error: CNAME loop
> ```

I need help with the setup of DNS. My mail server is hosted on ip 137.117.148.231 with domain: **mastermails.info**. Here I want to have IMAP server and SMTP server. How to setup **MX** and **PTR** records to make it work? The biggest problem I have with reverse DNS not found error that I get whenever I want to send something by SMT using my mail server.

Answer (score 0):

The reverse DNS (PTR) records need to be setup with your ISP - the entity that gave you the static IP address assignment.  Also for IMAP mailbox access, MX records don't factor in - only for sending email via SMTP.

Looking at your MX records, they seem completely misconfigured.  Typically, the priority is, from highest to lowest starting at 10,20,30,etc...This site should offer some insight: [MX Record Explanation](https://dnsdb.cit.cornell.edu/explain_mx.html)

As to the current MX record, smtp.mastermails.info isn't resolving for me and smtp.secureserver.net resolves to a different IP than the one you specified in your post, which means the SPF record won't even validate.

You need to fix the MX record to point to the appropriate SMTP servers, have your ISP configure your reverse DNS appropriately and build a proper SPF record (I've had success with this wizard in the past: [SPF Wizard](http://www.spfwizard.net/)).

Comment: My host is Azure Platform and as far as I know I have to setup reverse dns in txt -> spf records.
GoDaddy offers priority from lowest to highest.
smtp.mastermails.info isnt resolivng because my server is down at the moment

Comment: Your ISP needs to configure the reverse DNS for your IP address.  They control the reverse DNS for that zone since they own that netblock.  smtp.mastermails.info is the DNS name which GoDaddy's DNS servers is set to resolve (GoDaddy being the SOA of the mastermails.info DNS zone) for clients wanting to reach that server; your server being online or not shouldn't affect a DNS resolver being able to resolve the DNS name of the server to its IP address.

Comment: I see thankyout for help. I found that Azure platform doesnt offer reverse dns setup...

Comment: I used your spf wizard to create spf record and I got this:
v=spf1 mx a ~all
Unfortunately I get "Results - PermError SPF Permanent Error: CNAME loop" when checking if spf is valid.